# java setEnable(false) does not work

Tags: java, swing

When I press `JLabel`, I get a `mousePressed` event call in which I want to disable a `JButton`.  However, nothing happens.  Why is this?

Here is the `JLabel` `mousePress` event handler:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    get_clickevent(false)
}
```

Here is the function that get call on `mousePressed`:

```
public void get_clckevent(final boolean value){

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        boolean valu = value;

        public void run() {

            if (valu == false) {                   
                btnSave.setEnabled(false); //here is button that does not disable.
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is the runnable getting invoked? Try putting it directly in get__clcevent

Comment: There's no need for EventQueue.invokeLater here since the get_clckevent method is already called on the EDT.  But the main thing I can conclude from your post is that your error is not contained in any code you've posted so far.  If you haven't fixed this yet, simplify your code, create an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) and post it here.

Comment: are you sure you're calling right function? You call get_clickevent(), but disable button in get_clckevent(); it may be a typo in example though.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have looks free of problems.  Make sure btnSave is actually pointing to the button you think it is.  Also make sure your mouse event is actually happening. (Add a println somewhere to make sure your button is truly set to disabled).

Also instead of:

```
  if (valu == false) {
```

Just do:

```
  if (!valu) {
```

And what is the point of this line:

```
    boolean valu = value;
```

Just use value instead of valu in your if statement.

Comment: yes button is same that i want to disable but nothing happen.Is there problem in Event Dispatching thread ?.this button is Gui builder Button (drag and drop) not created by hand coded.

Comment: Are you sure it is the right button, did you do a println?  Also don't use a GUI Builder code it by hand especially if you are learning Swing.

Comment: Then you need to make sure your mouse event is really getting called. Did you add the mouse listener to a component?  Double check this side of things.

Comment: MouseListener is added to JLabel in which i call the function  get_clickevent(false) and mouse event is working.